# PHP Password Reset

Tags: php

I have been rewriting an old password reset to help learn PHP.

I was wondering if there are some parts I should renew as it is still getting errors.

```
if(isset($_POST['reset'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email");
    $stmt->execute(array("email"=>$email));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetchColumn();

    if($userRow == '0'){
        $error[] = 'Sorry, we cannot find your account details.  Please try another email address.';
    }else{
        $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT lname FROM users WHERE email=:email");
        $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$email));
        $userRow1=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //$userRow = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC($stmt);
        $password = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(),1)),3,10);
        $pass = md5($password);

        $to = "$email";
        $subject = "ClientCheck Account Recovery";
        $body = "Hi, $userRow1 \n\n Your password has been reset. \n\n Your password now is: $password \n\n Kind regards\n ClientCheck";

        $additionalheaders = "From: <no-reply@clientcheck.co.uk>";
        $additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: no-reply@clientcheck.co.uk";

        $stmt=$conn("UPDATE users SET password=:password WHERE email-:email");
        $stmt->execute(array(":password"=>$password,":email"=>$email));
        $userRow2=$stmt->rowCount();
    }
}

if(!empty($error)){
    $i = '0';
    while($i < count($error)){
        echo "$error[$i]";
        $i ++;
    }
}
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /forgottenpassword.php on line 31
>   Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /forgottenpassword.php on line 36

I know having a reset password sent is not the best step in terms of security but, I would like to get it right at this level then keep advancing to more secure resetting methods.

Comment: ahem `$stmt=$conn->prepare(` - look at your other query ;-) RTM http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: and please don't use MD5. You're using PDO with prepared statements. There is a safer function to use than MD5.

Comment: @Fred: PDO is not a substitute for hashing.

Comment: @symcbean I think you misinterpreted my comment.

Comment: @SaucedApples: Are you really asking if we think you should fix your bugs? Then yes, I for one think that would be a good idea. But while you are at it you might want to fix the issue that you storing an unsalted hash of a password - which is bad idea for security. And you might consider using a better hash algorithm than md5()

Comment: If you read it, it says renew not "should I fix".  It also explains at the bottom why I am doing it this way.  If you can't be bothered to read the question, why comment?

Comment: Then [**RTFM**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). The "syntax" error is obvious and you're not "paying attention" to comments left anywhere. @SaucedApples

Comment: I know, I've got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two lines must be corrected, the one in the variable $body which is an result array from PDO and the line where the statement is prepared:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reset'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email");
    $stmt->execute(array("email"=>$email));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetchColumn();

    if($userRow == '0'){
        $error[] = 'Sorry, we cannot find your account details.  Please try another email address.';
    }else{
        $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT lname FROM users WHERE email=:email");
        $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$email));
        $userRow1=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //$userRow = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC($stmt);
        $password = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(),1)),3,10);
        $pass = md5($password);

        $to = "$email";
        $subject = "ClientCheck Account Recovery";
        $body = "Hi, ".$userRow1['username']."\n\n Your password has been reset. \n\n Your password now is: $password \n\n Kind regards\n ClientCheck"; // changed here

        $additionalheaders = "From: <no-reply@clientcheck.co.uk>";
        $additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: no-reply@clientcheck.co.uk";

        $stmt=$conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET password=:password WHERE email=:email"); // changed here
        $stmt->execute(array(":password"=>$password,":email"=>$email));
        $userRow2=$stmt->rowCount();
    }
}

if(!empty($error)){
    $i = '0';
    while($i < count($error)){
        echo "$error[$i]";
        $i ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this line

```
$stmt=$conn("UPDATE users SET password=:password WHERE email-:email");
                                                            ^// this should be equals.
```

Comment: Thank I had missed that, but it does not solve the issues I'm afraid.

Comment: @SaucedApples, mark the error lines in your question.

Comment: The OP should RTM http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php they're doing it wrong in the line you showed as being the faulty method. I could've put in an answer, but I'll let you guys work it out.